# So many adjectives together

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence

> A specialised police unit arrested Majed, one of the **fugitive convicted Bangabandhu assassins**, as he returned home after hiding for nearly two and half decades in India.

I don't understand the meaning of bold part. I think it is not grammatical.

For full article

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/bangladesh-executes-ex-army-officer-for-assassinating-sheikh-mujibur-rahman/article31320564.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: It is correct. Each adjective applies to the noun. E.G., He drove an old rusty diesel Ashok lorry.

Answer (score 2):

It looks grammatical to me.
 The noun is "assassins". Working back from that, we have "Bangabandhu". Googling the term, I find it refers to a government policy in India, the proponent of which was assassinated in 1975.
Stepping back to the next word, "convicted" means that the assassins were convicted of the assassination in a court of law. Then we have "fugitive", which means that the assassins fled the law.
So, this compact series of three adjectives and one noun could be expanded into relative clauses:
"... assassins in the Bangabandhu affair who were convicted of the crime and who have been fugitives...".

I prefer the compact version.